# Variadic function to call lambda and pass parameters separately

Tags: c++

I want to call a lambda and pass the parameters separately.

e.g.:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T, typename... TS>
T call(T (*)(TS...) f, TS&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<TS...>(args...));
}
```

Thus I want to call this function like this:

```
call([](auto arg1, auto arg2){
    std::cout << arg1 << ", " << arg2 << std::endl;
}, 1, 2);
```

This should print out `1, 2`.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392935/wrap-a-function-pointer-in-c-with-variadic-template) is what you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just slap `...` everywhere and hope it works. Understand how [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) work and use the correct syntax. Furthermore, the function `call()` should not return `T`. Use `auto` for the return type. And `T` is already the full type of `f`, you should not write `T (*)(TS...)`. Here is the fixed version:

```
template<typename T, typename... TS>
auto call(T f, TS&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<TS>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that I still had the `...` in there. FYI the return is missing.